# How can I get doctrine query count from symfony2 profiler in production environment?

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.1, symfony-2.3

I need to check how many sql query is executed in production environment of Symfony2 application.

I tried following in my controller, but it displays me encoded string as result.

```
<?php
.....
.....
.....
class DefaultController extends Controller
{

    /**
     * @Route("/")
     * @Template()
     */
    public function testAction()
    {
        $profile = $this->container->get('profiler')->loadProfile($token);
        $data = $this->container->get('profiler')->export($profile);       
        print_r($data);
    }
}
.....
.....
```

Comment: In MySQL it is possible by using the query log. Information is available [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/query-log.html).

Comment: That is at sql server level, I need sql query count for particular route(url) and in controller or in service.

Comment: By default the profiler is only available in development.  Which makes sense because it does slow thing up significantly.  http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/profiler/matchers.html

Comment: @Cerad: yes, I made an answer but you're absolutely right. WP isn't registered in dev environment

Comment: Another approach is to use a Doctrine 2 SQL logger.  http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/dbal/2.4/class-Doctrine.DBAL.Logging.EchoSQLLogger.html.  It is what the profiler uses but I don't have a good example of configuring one inside of Symfony 2.

Comment: Thank you @Cerad, profile matchers works to enable profiler for particular ip

Comment: @RajeshMeniya: so you can access profiler from a controller (even in prod env)?

Comment: @DonCallisto: yes I can see it in browser, prod environment

Comment: @RajeshMeniya: if you can see it, does it means that you have enabled it explicitly. BTW see my answer

Answer (score 2):

Is not recommended to enable profiler in production environment also but...

Into a controller action you could do the following

```
$profiler = $this->container->get('profiler');
$profile = $profiler->loadProfile($token);

$queries = $profile->getCollector('db')->getQueries();
echo count($queries); //echo is just an example, you could - of course -
                      //use something like a logger
```

Comment: Ok I tryed the above in dev evnironment and got "Error: Call to a member function getCollector() on a non-object" got the token from $token = $this->get('security.token_storage')->getToken(); Any Idea ?